# How to set breakpoints when overriding theme variables in createMuiTheme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set the default theme typography font sizes to change based on breakpoints. For example, when the breakpoint is at the {xs} value, change theme.typography.h4.fontSize to '1.5rem'. At all other breakpoints, leave it at the default value ('2.125rem').

I can do this easily in components using the following code example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    title: {
        [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
            fontSize: '1.5rem',
        }
    },
}))
```

However, this means having to add the same code to every single component that has `<Typography variant='h4'>` in it. If I decide to change the value from '1.5rem' to '1.25rem', I would need to locate every single instance of `<Typography variant='h4'>` and change it manually.

Is there any way to add breakpoints to createMuiTheme so it applies to all instances?

I have attempted the following, which does not work:

```
const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme()

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        h4: {
            [defaultTheme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
                fontSize: '1.5rem'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**CORRECTION**: Initially I indicated that your solution didn't work because you were using an impossible condition, but I was incorrect. "down" from xs is inclusive of xs, so it does what you would want (matches 0px to 600px).

I'm not sure what I did in my initial testing that led me astray, but one thing that can cause confusion is if you have multiple `down` thresholds. In my own testing, I had an easier time avoiding shooting myself in the foot (e.g. by having a `breakpoints.down("xs")` followed by a later `breakpoints.down("sm")` that trumped the "xs" settings) by using `breakpoints.only`.

From https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/#breakpoints

> - xs, extra-small: 0px or larger
> - sm, small: 600px or larger

Here is an updated sandbox that shows a little more clearly what is happening:

[image: Edit w0591z46jl]

Comment: Ohhhh so simple! Yep, it works!! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9):

You can use custom breakpoints with **createBreakpoints**.

Here is an example changing the MuiButton

```
import createBreakpoints from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints'

const customBreakpointValues = {
  values: {
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576,
    md: 768,
    lg: 992,
    xl: 1200,
  },
}

const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({ ...customBreakpointValues })

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    ...customBreakpointValues,
  },
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          padding: '10px',
          [breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
            padding: '20px',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```