# breakpoint in material ui theme not changing font size for typography

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a  custom material ui theme, where I'm trying to add break points to the typography in this example h5 so that the font size is smaller when the screen is below the defined max-width. The media query is not even shown in the inspector. For some reason it's not being applied. Here is the relevant part of the code.

```
const breakpoints = {
  values: {
    xs: 0,
      sm: 0, // Phone
      md: 768, // Tablet/Laptop
      lg: 1500, // Desktop
      xl: 2000
  }
}

function myTheme (theme) {
  const mergedTheme = createMuiTheme({
    ...theme,
    breakpoints: breakpoints, 

    typography: {
      ...theme.typography,
      fontFamily: openSans,
      fontSize: 15,
      h5: {
        fontFamily: openSans,
        fontSize: '1.5625rem', // 25px
        [`& @media screen (max-width: ${breakpoints.values.lg}px)`]: {
          fontSize: '0.06785', //11px
        }
      } 
    }
  // I have also tried just returning 
  // the mergedTheme and not used the built responsiveFontSizes
  return responsiveFontSizes(mergedTheme)
})
```

I have also tried to use global overrided like it states in the docs here
https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/
using

```
overrides: {
  typography: {
    h5: {
      [`& @media screen (max-width: ${breakpoints.values.lg}px)`]: {
        fontSize: '0.06785', //11px
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And still can't get the media-query to work from the theme level. I can add media queries to the components just fine.

the generated html looks likes this.

```
<h5 class="MuiTypography-root-76 makeStyles-label-225 makeStyles-label-246 MuiTypography-h5-85 MuiTypography-colorSecondary-100">Meeting</h5>
```

the rules that are applied are this.

```
.makeStyles-label-246 {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.MuiTypography-h5-85 {
    font-size: 1.5625rem;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.16;
}
```

[this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385005/how-to-set-breakpoints-when-overriding-theme-variables-in-createmuitheme) are the closest to the issue I'm having. I tried using createBreakpoints like it said in the answer and also trying to target the component

```
components: {
      MuiTypography: {
        styleOverrides: {
          h5: {
            padding: '10px',
            [`@media query and screen(max-width: 1500px)`]: {
              fontSize: '8px',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

but still no dice.

Comment: Are you using v4 or v5 of Material-UI?  Your code references `createMuiTheme` which is the v4 name (changed to `createTheme` in v5), but the `components: { MuiTypography: { styleOverrides` structure in your last example is using v5 theme structure.

Comment: v4. The last example is what I took from the question linked above, just modified to my needs. Did not realize it was only valid for v5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some syntax issues that are getting in the way of this working. Below is a working version.

The main issues were:

- You don't want `&` in front of media queries
- You were missing `and` after `@media screen` in one of your code examples
- You had `'0.06785'` for the font size without any unit indicated. I used `"0.6785rem"` in my example, but not sure exactly what you meant to have.

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
const breakpoints = {
  values: {
    xs: 0,
    sm: 0, // Phone
    md: 768, // Tablet/Laptop
    lg: 1500, // Desktop
    xl: 2000
  }
};

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints,
  typography: {
    h5: {
      fontSize: "1.5625rem",
      [`@media screen and (max-width: ${breakpoints.values.lg}px)`]: {
        fontSize: "0.6785rem"
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Typography variant="h5">Hello World!</Typography>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Typography media query]

Comment: Okay I'm done coding for the day :( I was missing the and

Answer (score 1):

Material-UI has a specific api that you have to use to change the styling based on breakpoints. https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#default-breakpoints.
All you need to change is the media query section. `theme.breakpoints.down` will change the selected styling for screens less than and equal to the size specified. When you are creating the MUI theme, you have to create one temporarily to add to your main MUI theme.

```
typography: {
  ...theme.typography,
  fontFamily: openSans,
  fontSize: 15,
  h5: {
    fontFamily: openSans,
    fontSize: '1.5625rem', // 25px
    [createMuiTheme({breakpoints}).breakpoints.down('lg')]: {
      fontSize: '0.06785', //11px
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I manage responsive typography with little different way with React Typescript:

I create one function to handle responsive task:

```
// make font size responsive
interface responsiveFontType {
  sm: number;
  md: number;
  lg: number;
}
export function responsiveFontSizes({ sm, md, lg }: responsiveFontType) {
  return {
    [`@media only screen and (min-width: ${themeBreakPoint.values.sm}px)`]: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(sm),
    },
    [`@media only screen and (min-width: ${themeBreakPoint.values.md}px)`]: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(md),
    },
    [`@media only screen and (min-width: ${themeBreakPoint.values.lg}px)`]: {
      fontSize: pxToRem(lg),
    },
  };
}
```

```
// ---------------------------------------------------
// typography customization

export const themeTypography = () => {
  // font family define
  const FONT_PRIMARY = "'Roboto', sans-serif";
  const SUBTITLE_FONT = "'Times New Roman', Times, serif";
  const SUBTITLE_FONT2 = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";

  return {
    fontFamily: FONT_PRIMARY,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeightLight: 300,
    fontWeightRegular: 400,
    fontWeightMedium: 500,
    fontWeightBold: 700,

    title: {
      fontFamily: FONT_PRIMARY,
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontSize: pxToRem(24),
      ...responsiveFontSizes({ sm: 16, md: 20, lg: 24 }),
    },

    subtitle1: {
      fontFamily: SUBTITLE_FONT,
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: pxToRem(20),
      ...responsiveFontSizes({ sm: 15, md: 18, lg: 20 }),
    },

    subtitle2: {
      fontFamily: SUBTITLE_FONT2,
      fontWeight: 400,
      fontSize: pxToRem(18),
      ...responsiveFontSizes({ sm: 14, md: 16, lg: 18 }),
    },

    button: {
      fontWeight: 700,
      lineHeight: 24 / 14,
      fontSize: pxToRem(14),
      textTransform: "capitalize",
    },
  } as TypographyOptions;
};
```

> My create theme function

```
export const theme = () => {
  return createTheme({
    palette: themePalette(),

    breakpoints: themeBreakPoint,

    typography: themeTypography(),
  });
};
```

I think this make easier to handle things more correctly...