# Material UI - React: How to add breakpoints in CustomTheme for typography

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui and React to create SPA.

I am facing one issue where I want to make my pages response for smaller screen size. So I have to add `fontSize: { xs: '30px', md: '56px' }` in every text. I want to know if there is a way to do the same thing in my custom theme.

theme.js file

```
const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        mode: 'light',
        primary: {
            main: '#3f51b5',
            button: {
                bgColor: colors.buttonBgColor,
                borderColor: colors.buttonBgColor,
                hoverColor: colors.white
            },
            navBar: {
                topBarBgColor: colors.white
            }
        }
    },
    typography: {
        allVariants: { color: colors.black },
        fontFamily: roboto.style.fontFamily,
        hoverColor: colors.buttonBgColor,
        white: colors.white,
        h1: {
            fontSize: '56px',
            fontWeight: 600
        },
        h6: {
            fontSize: '17px',
            color: '#505556'
        },
        subtitle2: {
            fontSize: '17px',
            fontWeight: 400
        }
    }
});

export default theme;
```

I tried alot of thing from below but did not work.

[breakpoint in material ui theme not changing font size for typography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68490075/breakpoint-in-material-ui-theme-not-changing-font-size-for-typography)

Comment: I think you're doing it right, have wrapped your app with the theme provider and gave it the theme as a prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this thing perfectly work for me. I have created it in new project so please use this one.

```
// theme.js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    h1: {
      fontSize: '56px',
      '@media (max-width:960px)': {
        fontSize: '100px',
      },
      '@media (max-width:600px)': {
        fontSize: '10px',
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

and here is my used file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import theme from './assets/style/theme'; // Path to your theme file

const MyComponent = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h1">Heading 1</Typography>
    </div>
  </ThemeProvider>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

Make sure you have properly imported theme file and give it to your app.js or index.js